# Python: Better way to search and collect text strings from html. Strip off markdowns, tags, etc

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, nltk

There are many modules like lxml, Beautiful soup, nltk and pyenchant to correctly filter out proper english words.
But then what is the cleanest shortest way like html2text offers, also if markdowns could be stripped off as well
(While I write, there are scores of possible similar questions on the right)
There could be a universal regex which could take away all the html tags?

```
def word_parse(f):
    raw = nltk.clean_html(f) #f = url.content here, from "requests" module
    regex = r'[a-zA-Z]+' # | ^[a-zA-Z]+\b'
    match = re.compile(regex)
    ls = []
    for line in raw.split():
        for mat in line.split():
            try:
                v = match.match(mat).group()
                map(ls.append, v.split())
            except AttributeError, e:
                pass
```

Is there some good code snippet somebody could suggest? Can someone suggest a much cleaner and optimized code here?

Comment: `except AttributeError, e:` this syntax is depricated, use `except AttributeError as e:` instead, but in your case, because you don't want to do anything with exception, you can use this form: `except AttributeError:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend going with an existing library rather than trying to write your own regexps for this.  Other people have put considerable work into Beautiful Soup, just for instance, and you might as well benefit from it.

For this specific case, Beautiful Soup offers the [get_text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method:

```
text = BeautifulSoup(f).get_text()
```

Comment: +1 wow.if you could guide as to how the unicode could be removed (as in u'some string') that will be It.

Comment: Encode it to whatever encoding you want, e.g. `text.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: what abt: dammit = UnicodeDammit(u"some_eg_there") + 
temp = dammit.unicode_markup ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking there.  The returned text is a Unicode string; encode is how you convert that into a byte string in a specific encoding.